# Android Listview Items getting hidden under app bar

Tags: android, listview

Im following this course. I have set an array with A,B,C,D,E,F. However when the app is launched few entries (A,B,C) are getting hidden under the app bar layout.

I have set the co-ordinates properly for the list view.. Pl find the screen shot. Kindly let me know how to fix this. [Pl find the screen shot showing listview entries getting hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVsOT.png)

Please find the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/nameListView"
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="807dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please upload your layout.xml file

Comment: You should also upload your layout file so that everyone else can see and help you out.

Comment: Change your width and height to `0dp`; the height of the ListView is probably taller than your phone, so it is getting its top and bottom cut off.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make use of constraint, in this case are both width and height, you need to set

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

Here is the docs about it https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout

Comment: This is not an answer please write this as a comment.